# Why is the following map function returning the strings with commas?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm looping through an object. If one of its keys matches the value of another `fields` object then return the value of `type` of that `fields` object:

```
// OBJECTS

user: {
  email: '',
  password: ''
}

formFields: [
  { name: 'email', type: 'text', required: true },
  { name: 'password', type: 'password', required: true }
]

// HTML

<input :type="getPropType($key)"

// FUNCTION

getPropType (key) {
  console.log(this.fields)
  console.log(key)
  return this.fields.map(field => {
    if (field.name === key) return field.type
  })
}
```

It works except a comma is returned with every `field.type`:

[image]

Which is strange since the logs don't output any commas:

[image]

What could be the cause?

Comment: Where are the coma, it is the one's after `Object`?

Comment: The one in `text,`

Comment: I think you might need `this.fields.filter(field => field.name === key).map(field => field.type)`, else the resulting array could have undefined values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to extract the `type` of the object with the same name as the value of key, in that case a more appropriate solution will be to do that exactly that - ie find the element with the given name then extract its type

```
getPropType(key) {
  console.log(this.fields)
  console.log(key);
  var type;
  this.fields.some(field => {
    if (field.name === key) {
      type = field.type;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return type
}
```

---

If you want to use `.map()`, then

```
return this.fields.filter(field => field.name === key).map(field => field.type).join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.map() returns array. Your "getPropType" returned ["text", ""] and it should be reduced in your case.

```
return this.fields.map(field => {
    if (field.name === key) return field.type
  }).reduce(function(prev, curr, index, array){return prev + curr});
```

Comment: Anyway, solution of @Arun P Johny looks much better than mine.